# Collapse an accordion menu

Tags: javascript

I have this simple collapsible menu on [www.keokuk.com](http://www.keokuk.com)
I would like for the previous menu to close when you click on the next one.

this is the javascript:

```
<script>
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight) {
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";

        }
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Please may you edit the question so the code is a [mcve]? Also add a description about what is currently wrong with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on a solution on your website.

But it appears you set max-height manually in an other javascript function so you can just do the same thing in the commented line.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible').forEach(el => {
el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible').forEach(e => {
        e.classList.remove('active');
        e.nextSibling.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = "0px";
    });

    e.target.classList.toggle('active');
    e.target.nextSibling.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight =
        `${el.nextSibling.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight}px`;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Greg thank you. I replaced everything inside the  Script tag (after var coll  = with this and then put in 40 px for the maximun height.. When I uploaded the buttons wouldnt open at all. any thoughts? see www.keokuk.com/indextest.html

Comment: It appears that each buttons don't trigger the eventListener, no class active added on click. It saw the script in the console and it's because 40px is not a string (just 0 can be a number meaning "0px" :)  )
I will update the answer, you can also uncomment line 10 by assigning the wanted max-height property (I've tested with "200px" and it works :) )

Comment: YES YES YES!! That does it!! OK this is my first time using stackoverflow... I need to see how to give you the highest thumbs up possible!! Thank you Greg so very much!!

Comment: You're welcome :D Appreciate !

Comment: Greg would you mind taking a look at it.. www.keokuk.com now when I click button it opens but if I reclick it to close it wont close until i click a different link.

Comment: Thank for following issue, Yes I forgot to change e.target.classList.add('active'); by e.target.classList.toggle('active');
@EdVinson You can change the line and also "5000px" is too high :D ! Maybe a value "400px" can be enought ;)

Comment: When I did anything less than 5000px (approx) for the max height, the list cut off "Known Businesses" about halfway down on mobile device. the other categories werent so populated but that one is perhaps the most important. Gonna try your latest comment, thank you!

Comment: Fisrt time I took a look in your code, I saw max-height was automatically set in the content with a good value. Do you know how ? You should apply the good value like before. Can you check ?

Comment: Greg yes I saved the original script but how can I send it to you please? i have it in a notepad file. not sure if I have enough characters left here: if (content.style.maxHeight) {
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";

Comment: Of course ! That's all we needed :D Great ! The final answer is updated

Comment: OK I replaced but none open now: http://keokuk.com/indextest2.html dang sorry to be such a pain

Comment: was missing last little brackets...they open now but wont close when you reclick on the same button to close.

Comment: how does it perform on your end? www.keokuk.com/indextest2.html the height is ok now but clicking a same button the second time doesnt collapse.

Comment: It must work. It's like an other javascript function is executed on button clic, an add class active instant after class active must be remove by the solution. You should investigate, only knows you code :)

Comment: Im going to try taking that WOWSlider off the page to test and see if that's where its coming from. Not much else on there besides that to be conflicting. Thank you Greg.

Comment: I have stripped the page of everything else yet clicking on the same button doesnt collapse it's group. I can live with it though if it cant be fixed> http://www.keokuk.com/indextest3.html

Answer (score 0):

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Collect all .switch into an array
const switches = [...document.querySelectorAll(".switch")];

// Bind each .switch to the click event
switches.forEach(s => s.addEventListener("click", openClose));

// Event handler passes Event Object as default
function openClose(event) {
  // Reference the tag proceeding clicked tag
  const content = this.nextElementSibling;
  // Get the height of content
  let maxHt = content.scrollHeight + 'px';
  // Find the index position of clicked tag
  let index = switches.indexOf(this);
  // The clicked tag will toggle .active class
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  // Remove .active class from all .switch
  switches.forEach((btn, idx) => {
    /*
    If current index does NOT equal index of 
    clicked tag...
    ...remove .active 
    */
    if (idx != index) {
      btn.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
  /*
  If clicked has .active class...
  ...set style property of max-height using CSS variables
  */
  if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
    content.style.setProperty('--maxH', maxHt + 'px');
  } else {
    content.style.setProperty('--maxH', '0px');
  }
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

:root {
  font: 300 1.5ch/1.2 'Segoe UI';
  --maxH: 0px;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200%;
  padding: 15px;
}

header {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 3px ridge black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  max-height: var(--maxH);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 3px ridge black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #ddd;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.active+section {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<header class='switch'>Read more...</header>
<section>
  <p>Merchandise Morty, your only purpose in life is to buy &amp; consume merchandise and you did it, you went into a store an actual honest to god store and you bought something, you didn't ask questions or raise ethical complaints you just looked into
    the bleeding jaws of capitalism and said 'yes daddy please' and I'm so proud of you, I only wish you could have bought more, I love buying things so much Morty. Morty, you know outer space is up right? Are you kidding? I'm hoping I can get to both
    of them, Rick! And there's no evidence that a Latino student did it.</p>
</section>

<header class='switch'>Read more...</header>
<section>
  <p>Oh, I'm sorry Morty, are you the scientist or are you the kid who wanted to get laid? Why don't you ask the smartest people in the universe, Jerry? Oh yeah you can't. They blew up. Looossseeerrrrr. I am not putting my father in a home! He just came
    back into my life, and you want to, grab him and, stuff him under a mattress like last month's Victoria's Secret?!
  </p>
</section>
```